# Where to split BTC

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I have my BTC in a paper wallet. What exchange or wallet can I deposit into that will split it into BTC and BCH? And then allow me to withdraw both? 
The exchange I have used and withdrew my BTC from pre-split is now trading BCH but not splitting any BTC that wasn't on their exchange at time of split.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you haven't figured it out yet, these are the steps I've used yesterday to successfully split the two from my paper wallet.

1. Install [Electrum](https://electrum.org/) bitcoin wallet, create a standard wallet and import your private key in it.
2. Send the *full* BTC balance to another paper wallet (or an exchange or elsewhere) - this is done to make sure that on the later steps you don't lose your BTC balance
3. Install [Electron Cash](http://www.electroncash.org/) - Bitcion cash wallet. It will look pretty much like Electrum as it's Electrum's fork modified to work with BCH
4. Import the same private key as the above into Electron Cash - you should see the bitcoin cash balance.
5. Send the balance to a new paper wallet (different from the wallet you have sent your bitcoin on step 2). Paper wallets for BTC and BCH are compatible so to get one for BCH you use the same online generation tools as for BTC

And that's it really.