# Blockchain.info Paper Wallet

Tags: wallet-recovery, paper-wallet

I created a [Blockchain.info](http://Blockchain.info) paper wallet back in 2014. At the time I used a passphrase which only contained 8 words as the recovery seed as per the instructions. When I try to scan the public key QR code in order to check the balance I get the following "http://qr-to/banAvd".  The public key is `"13gmfrUCaRB1dZB2RftmoDVYd7jjSyhq32"`.

Comment: and what is the question itself? your 13gmf... is neither public key nor valid bitcoin address. we are happy that you did something wrong three years ago but this information is absolutely useless

Comment: Could be one of several formats and compressions for public key. The sure way is to figure it out from the private key.

Comment: @ amaclin is it not a 33 char address base 58?

Comment: @mc my english is poor, aren't you understand my comment above? there is no question, no info, no clues, but some garbage and broken link.

Comment: I think it is a 33 byte compressed public key

Comment: @amaclin - you don't need to be rude or condescending. The question is quite clear - the guy is asking what to do. If you feel like there is not enough info you can ask for it, or ignore the question altogether, but please don't behave like a jerk

Comment: the correct address is 13gmfrUCaRB1dZB2RftmoDVYd7jjSyhq3**2**

Comment: @amaclin - do you think that I could also find the missing character in the private key that I have?

Answer (score 0):

From amaclin's comment about one digit missing in your public address above, you can checs your balance here (BTC 0.01840202): https://bitref.com/13gmfrUCaRB1dZB2RftmoDVYd7jjSyhq32

After that you can do the following:

1. Download and install any bitcoin desktop wallet. e.g. Electrum (https://electrum.org/#home)
2. Import your PRIVATE KEY that you find in your paper wallet into that Electrum wallet. It will show you the balance and allow to move the money to another paper wallet or an exchange (if you want to sell it)

IMPORTANT: as your bitcoin is pre-split (which happened earlier in August) that private address that you have also contains an equal amount of Bitcoin Cash. 
These are the steps I went thru to get mine: 
[Where to split BTC](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57728/where-to-split-btc/58593#58593)

Comment: this is not a "compressed public key", but an address without one symbol at the end

Comment: When I attempt to import the private key from my blockchain.info paper wallet into my bitcoin core wallet an error occurs "invalid key". Any Ideas?

Comment: The length of my blockchaininfo paper wallet private key starts with a "5". The total length including characters and numbers is 50.  Shouldn't it be 51? Confused.

Comment: That's correct, it should start with 5 and it has a length of 51 characters total. Did you print it out or wrote down by hand? Could you have missed the last character? You can try brute force add a 51st character trying 0-9 and a-z

Comment: I used a printer. Brute forcing the last character did not work. Also, I have tried the mnemonic (8 words) that can be used to recover the password on "https://blockchain.info/wallet/recover-wallet" however it also fails.

Comment: Not sure what else you can try. At least the good thing is you don't have much left on that wallet.

Comment: I have a printed copy of the mnemonic to recover the password when i created the BlockchainInfo legacy wallet but that doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a public key in a common 33 byte compressed form. I generated an address from it

12r9cntQ5T8o6mELxxcj1RwBZiKGVV

to check the balance and bitref says it has 0.0 bitcoins sent or received.

Also zero transactions for that wallet.

Comment: What service did you use to generate an uncompressed public key? I haven't found one

Comment: I think the guys is confused. That's why the easiest way for him is to import the paper wallet into a desktop wallet using the private key. That is, if he has ever actually transferred the bitcoin there :)

Comment: I find blockchain does not work with the public key, but the address. I used a site first to hash 160 the compressed public key, then use hash to generate an address for the purpose of checking balance. http://bitcoinvalued.com/tools.php

Comment: Blockchain does indeed work with uncompressed public keys, but it dies not work with compressed ones.